# npm err! code 1 when performing npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I have looked at the other posts concerning other people who had this or similar problems and those fixes don't seem to be working for me. When I run "npm install" I constantly get the line "npm ERR! code 1"

This is preventing me form getting to test my code as I can't install my node modules.
Here is part the output:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/myname/Documents/blip/blip-api-billbot/node_modules/mongodb-client-encryption
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install --tag-prefix node-v || node-gyp rebuild
```

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "blip-api-billbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Blip's billbot architecture for creating links to biller accounts.",
  "main": "chrome-script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "linuxRebuild": "docker run --rm -v '$PWD':/var/task lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x npm rebuild"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.13",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.824.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "axios-cookiejar-support": "^1.0.1",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "bindings": "^1.5.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^5.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "lambda-packager": "^0.2.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongodb-client-encryption": "^1.1.0",
    "node-downloader-helper": "^1.0.15",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "puppeteer": "^2.1.1",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.1.15",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker": "^2.11.9",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-repl": "^2.2.8",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.6.5",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "serverless-docker-artifacts": "^0.1.1",
    "serverless-dotenv-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^5.12.1",
    "serverless-plugin-scripts": "^1.0.2",
    "tough-cookie": "^4.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuid-mongodb": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: provide the package.json

Comment: just added it above